# Hiding initial value in Imported Database Model of Enterprise Architect

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect

I am currently creating database model by doing reverse-engineering MS SQL Server 2008 into Sparx's Enterprise Architect version 10.

I have been able to import tables, and hide items that are not required (such operations and stereotypes). However, I did not find the option to hide for Column `Initial` values when importing tables or in diagram properties, which left me the option to edit each column one by one (time consuming).

Do I miss any configuration to hide the `Initial` value? If such configuration does not exist, what is the best method to hide/remove the Initial value without configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution by creating EA script. Feels free to use and enhance it :)

```
!INC Local Scripts.EAConstants-JScript

function OnProjectBrowserScript()
{
    // Show the script output window
    Repository.EnsureOutputVisible( "Script" );

    var treeSelectedType = Repository.GetTreeSelectedItemType();

    switch ( treeSelectedType )
    {
        case otElement: // if select table
        {
            removeInitial(Repository.GetContextObject());
            break;
        }
        case otPackage: // if select package containing table
        {
            var selectedObject as EA.Element;
            selectedObject = Repository.GetContextObject();

            for ( var i = 0 ; i < selectedObject.Elements.Count ; i++ )
            {
                removeInitial(selectedObject.Elements.GetAt( i ));
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            // Error message
            Session.Prompt( "This script does not support items of this type.", promptOK );
        }
    }
}

function removeInitial(selectedObject)
{
    for (var i = 0 ; i < selectedObject.Attributes.Count; i++)
    {
        var attrib as EA.Attribute;
        attrib = selectedObject.Attributes.GetAt(i);
        attrib.Default = "";
        attrib.Update();
    }
    Session.Output("finished updating " + selectedObject.Name);

}

OnProjectBrowserScript();
```